# ReferenceError: stripeResponseHandler is not defined - FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, strip

I am having an issue with using my Stripe connection in only Firefox, Chrome works perfect.

When I try to send card information to Stripe in Firefox (most recent) it tells me:

```
ReferenceError: stripeResponseHandler is not defined
```

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/v2"></script>
       .....
       .....
                    // set publish key for stripe
                    Stripe.setPublishableKey('myToken');
                    // validate information
                    Stripe.card.createToken({
                        number: $('.cardnumber').val(),
                        cvc: $('.cw').val(),
                        exp_month: $('.expmonth option:selected').val(),
                        exp_year: $('.expyear option:selected').val(),
                        name: $(".cardholderfullname").val(),
                        address_line1: $(".address").val(),
                        address_city: $(".city").val(),
                        address_state: $("#state option:selected").val(),
                        address_zip: $(".zipcode").val()
                    }, stripeResponseHandler);
                    // error handling and success sending
                    function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
                        if (response.error) {
                            $("#message").fadeIn();
                            $("#message").html("The card information you entered was not valid, please check to make sure all information is correct.");
                        } else {
                            sendArray.token = response['id'];
                            $(sendArray).serialize();
                            //console.log(sendArray);
                            $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "JSON",
                            url: '../member/functions/stripeAcc/makeCustomer.php',
                            data: sendArray ,
                            success: function(response) {
                            }
                            });
                            closeDialogBox();
                        }
                    }
..... more
```

Suggestions and thoughts?

Comment: when you check the network tab of firefox developer tools, do you see that "../js/v2" is loaded correct?

Comment: it says..GET mySite.com/js/v2 HTTP/1.1 200 OK 288ms

Comment: @johnSmith any idea what might be wrong?